# What happens when an Unseen Servant is forced to make a saving throw?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw

An Unseen Servant has an AC of 10 and 1 hit point, which means that it can be targeted by actions and effects that use attack rolls, and that it can be destroyed by taking damage.

However, the spell text doesn't have any information about its saving throws. What happens if it is targeted by a area spell or effect that requires a saving throw, such as Fireball?

Comment: It asks for a d20. (Unseen servants don't have pockets).

Comment: Fireball only does damage to creatures, so the unseen servant wouldn't be hurt either way.

Answer (score 11):

### Firstly, an unseen servant isn't a creature

> This spell creates an invisible, mindless, **shapeless force** that performs simple tasks at your command until the spell ends.

The presence of an AC and HP value does not make it a creature, even objects (such as Bigby's Hand, Barrels, and Walls) have AC and HP (and a strength score, in the case of Bigby's Hand). As for the Servant having a Strength score, I suspect it's for determining how much it can lift, drag or carry.

Because the Unseen Servant isn't a creature, most spells that can target a single creature (if the caster can see invisibility), can't legally target it, neither can Area of Effect spells that hits creatures, such as Hypnotic Pattern, affect it.

It can, however, take damage from Area spells that deal at least 1 damage- then it is destroyed.

Comment: I understand that it's not a creature, but it doesn't quite seem like an object either. Does that mean that it automatically fails its saving throws against spells like Fireball, Lightning Bolt, and Meteor Swarm? Or, if it's an object, does it somehow catch fire?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it saves, I think? The 1 HP means it's gonna die even if it does save. Unless, I can't really exhaustively search, but is there a spell that is an area of effect and doesn't do damage on a save?

Comment: As your main argument is that it's not a creature, wouldn't the phrase "is destroyed" be more appropriate than "dies?"

Comment: @daze413, ah, I forgot about that. I think this is the right answer then.

Comment: While the 5e version of the spell doesn't say what happens when an unseen servant would make a saving throw, both 3.5e and Pathfinder do - an unseen servant doesn't get a save against any form of attack (i.e., it automatically fails the save).

Comment: @BenS. That's true but I wouldn't necessarily put it as guidance, but thanks anyway!